# Why did Garrus disappear from my ship?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I just did some side quests after Tuchunka (I forgot how it's spelled exactly, sorry.) and I went back to my ship to speak with Garrus, because he's one of my favorite characters. I find that he isn't there. I press V to open my ship map, go through all the areas, and he's nowhere to be seen. Everyone else is there, and I'm pretty sure I didn't do anything to make him leave. (If that's even possible.) It's sort of worrying me, because he's the most important person that I take along on missions. *Yes, I've become attached to a video game character.*

But seriously, is this a glitch or did I do something in-game to make him get fed up and leave?

Comment: Try playing another combat mission where you have to choose your party.  If he doesn't show up in the squad selection screen then you might have a problem.

Comment: Are you at the Citadel? Sometimes characters show up on the Citadel instead of on the ship while you're docked

Comment: Found him! Thanks to prior answer I decided to check every where. He's over in the lounge (Kasumi's old room)

Answer (score 5):

Try looking around your ship. Sometimes characters move about the ship and chatter with other people aboard. For example, I found Dr. Chakwas in the crew quarters while the Krogan female was aboard the ship.

I don't know where he might be, but he's on that ship somewhere!

Comment: If you bring up the map (press left stick on 360) and go through the decks, it will show where Garrus is located on the ship.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like a glitch to me. If he really doesn't show up anywhere on the ship, that seems like the only answer.

Answer (score -1):

He is with joker often chatting :) look there

Comment: That's not the only alternative place to find Garrus

Answer (score -1):

I found him chatting with Liara in the port observation room where Kasumi used to hang out. The bad side of the fact that they can move around is that usually when they've moved, you don't get the normal conversation wheel. So if you wanted to talk to them like that you'd have to wait until they show up back in their spot.